# systemd state to remain active on failed ExecStop

Tags: systemd, alma-linux

When an error occurs with the `ExecStop=/usr/lib/pick/d3shutdown_custom pick0` script, I want systemd to abort the shutdown process and return to the `active` state.

At the moment when the script exits with code 4 (the user has insufficient privileges), systemd is stuck in the `deactivating` state.

Here's my systemd service file

```
[Unit]
Description=D3 multivalue database
After=d3_sn.service rslm.service
Requires=rslm.service
Wants=d3_sn.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/d3 -n pick0 -s -a x
ExecStop=/usr/lib/pick/d3shutdown_custom pick0
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=true
SuccessExitStatus=11

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's a snippet of the `d3shutdown_custom` script

```
log_error() {
    echo -e "Error: $1"
    echo "Aborting program ... "
    echo " "
}

if [ ! -f "$D3_PROPERTIES_FILE" ]; then log_error "File $D3_PROPERTIES_FILE not found."; exit 2; fi
source $D3_PROPERTIES_FILE
export PICKUSER
export PICKUPASS

if d3 -q | grep -q 'not running'; then
        exit 11
fi

D3TCL=$(/usr/bin/d3tcl 'listu')
if echo $D3TCL | grep -q 'Bad User or User Password'; then log_error "Bad password"; exit 4; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a tricky request.  When you `systemctl stop` something, it **should** and **will** always go down.  It may fail, but it will eventually stop even if `systemd` has to [`FinalKillSignal=(SIGKILL)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#FinalKillSignal=) it after [`TimeStopSec=(90s)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStopSec=).

If your condition failed, then, then things like "shutdown" or "reboot" will not be possible, and these things should always be possible.

I think the best way to implement this would be with a [`Conflicts=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) unit and one that conditionally starts the conflicting unit via [`OnFailure=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=).  That would mean you need to change your thinking from `systemctl stop my-unit` to `systemctl start maybe-kill-my-unit`.

This is how shutdown works.  We don't stop other units, we `systemctl start shutdown.target`.

You could further enforce the use of `c.service` by preventing people from using `systemctl stop a.service` directly with [`RefuseManualStop=yes`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RefuseManualStart=) .

```
a.service
[Unit]
Description=Long running service
RefuseManualStop=yes

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 60
```

```
b.service
[Unit]
Description=Killer of the long running service
Conflicts=a

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
```

```
c.service
[Unit]
Description=Conditional killer of the long runing service
OnFailure=b

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Here's an example of it in action (where `c` fails).

```
$ systemctl --user start a
$ systemctl --user start c 
Job for c.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

$ systemctl --user status a b c --lines 0
● a.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/a.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-10-09 16:10:18 CEST; 3s ago

● b.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/b.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-10-09 16:10:18 CEST; 3s ago

● c.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/c.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-09 16:10:18 CEST; 3s ago

$ journalctl --user -u a -u b -u c --since "1 minute ago"
Oct 09 16:10:14: Long running service
Oct 09 16:10:18: Starting Conditional killer of the long runing service
Oct 09 16:10:18: c.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 09 16:10:18: c.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Oct 09 16:10:18: Starting Killer of the long running service...
Oct 09 16:10:18: Stopping Long running service...
Oct 09 16:10:18: Finished Killer of the long running service.
```

And here's an example where `c` succeeds:

```
$ systemctl --user start a
$ systemctl --user start c
$ systemctl --user status a b c --lines 0
● a.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/a.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-09 16:14:45 CEST; 9s ago

● b.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/b.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)

● c.service
     Loaded: loaded (.config/systemd/user/c.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)

$ journalctl --user -u a -u b -u c --since "1 minute ago"
Oct 09 16:14:45: Started Long running service.
Oct 09 16:14:50: Starting Conditional killer of the long runing service...
Oct 09 16:14:50: Finished Conditional killer of the long runing service.
```

This example will stop `a` if `c` fails.  If your script is inverted (should stop if `c` succeeds) you can play with [`SuccessExitStatus=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#SuccessExitStatus=).

---

If you have a super recent version of systemd, you can make this more elegant with [`ExecCondition=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecCondition=) combined with [`OnSuccess=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnSuccess=).  This will avoid leaving any units in a failed state, avoid contaminating your global "degraded" `systemctl status` and avoid leaving error messages on stderr.  To do this, let `ExecCondition=` run your script.  If it succeeds, then `ExecStart=` will succeed and the `OnSuccess=` action will trigger `b.service`, killing `a.service`.  If `ExecCondition=` fails, then `ExecStart=` will never run and `OnSuccess=` will never trigger, allowing `a.service` to live.

```
c.service
[Unit]
OnSuccess=b.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecCondition=/your-script
ExecStart=/bin/true
```